# Getting Ptython Error with OLS Anova table - statsmodels

Tags: python-3.x, statsmodels

I am trying to create an ANOVA with `statsmodels` and getting an error

[[table image]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Lv5A.png)

```
variable    value
```

0   x-y-20  -0.070000
1   x-y-20  0.090000
2   x-y-20  0.080000
3   x-y-20  -0.030000

code

```
melt_t['variable'].replace({'x-y-20':'set-a','x-y-40':'set-b','x-y-60':'set-c'}, inplace=True)
results = ols('value ~ Q(variable)', data=melt_t).fit()
results.summary()
```

error

```
PatsyError: Error evaluating factor: TypeError: 'Series' objects are mutable, thus they cannot be hashed
    value ~ Q(variable)
            ^^^^^^^^^^^
```

I am trying to get the following table 
https://i0.wp.com/pythonfordatascience.org/wp-content/uploads/2018/04/anova-statsmodel-results-1.png?w=613&ssl=1

Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure you actually *need* the `Q()` transformation, but if you do need/want to use it, it seems you have omitted necessary quotation marks around `variable`:

```py
data = {'variable': {0: 'x-y-20', 1: 'x-y-40', 2: 'x-y-60', 3: 'x-y-20'},
        'value': {0: -0.07, 1: 0.09, 2: 0.08, 3: -0.03}}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df['variable'].replace({'x-y-20':'set-a','x-y-40':'set-b','x-y-60':'set-c'}, inplace=True)
results = smf.ols('value ~ Q("variable")', data=df).fit()
results.summary()
```

gives (excerpted):

```
                             coef    std err          t      P>|t|      [0.025      0.975]
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Intercept                 -0.0500      0.020     -2.500      0.242      -0.304       0.204
Q("variable")[T.set-b]     0.1400      0.035      4.041      0.154      -0.300       0.580
Q("variable")[T.set-c]     0.1300      0.035      3.753      0.166      -0.310       0.570
```

(I get the same table using `'value ~ variable'` without `Q()`.)

Comment: Thank you @brendan! You're right. It works when I remove the 'Q'. Thanks!

Comment: @RTP Glad this worked for you. Please consider accepting / upvoting if you found this helpful.